# blink with green color .drop div when .drag is dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I want to blink the .drop div when .drag is dragged.

And when the .drag div was droped or reverted I want that the .drop div stop blinking.

But I want to blink with colors, with green color for example, but I dont see how with fadeTo().

Do you know how to fix my code to achieve this?

Example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/8t9v5tpq/2/

Code:

```
$(".drag").draggable({
  revert: 'invalid',
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    $('.drop').fadeTo('fast',0).fadeTo('fast',1);
  }
});

$('.drop').droppable({
  over: function(event, ui) {
     $('.drop').fadeTo('fast',0).fadeTo('fast',0);
    ui.draggable.remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you want it to blink with a different color each blink, or green every time?

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing the background color of the div, when `.drag` is picked up

```
$(".drag").draggable({
  revert: 'invalid',
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    $('.drop').fadeTo('fast',0)
    $('.drop').css('background-color', 'green')
    $('.drop').fadeTo('fast',1);
  }

});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8t9v5tpq/3/)

Comment: Thanks, but do you know, after the .drag div is dropped, or if the .drag div is reverted to the original position, how to stop the blink?

Comment: No, I cannot. I have worked out how to make the `background-color `change back, but not the blinking.

Comment: One thing I can say, the div does stop blinking, it just takes about a minute. It seems that the code is executes each time the mouse moves, therefore moving it across the screen can result in it being executed hundreds of times. You may be able to use the `start` and `stop` events rather than the `drag` event, to set a variable to `true` on start, and `false` on stop. Then all you need is a loop to regularly check if the variable is `true` and execute code.

Answer (score 1):

This code can solve your problem.

```
<div id="cuadrado" class="drop" style="background:gray; margin-top:50px; width:100px; height:100px;"> drop</div>

<script>
$('.drop').droppable({

  over: function(event, ui) {
     document.getElementById("cuadrado").style.color="green";
     document.getElementById("cuadrado").style.background="green";
     $('.drop').fadeTo('fast',0).fadeTo('fast',0);
    ui.draggable.remove();

  }
});
</script>
```

[image]

Running the code the following is obtained:

[image]

I hope it helps you.

bye @locoalien